# Run something just before a change to a tab's history occurs in Firefox addons

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to attach a piece of code inside a tab's `window` from my Firefox addon, so it will run just before a change happens occurs in the tab's history — e.g., the user clicks the back or forward buttons, the user clicks on a link to a new page…

Is there a relevant high/low level API to do this?

My initial idea was to attach code to `window.onbeforeunload`, but that doesn't work on websites that use `window.history.pushState()`, and doesn't run when the user clicks the back/forward button manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `pagehide` and `pageshow` events to fir on both push state and unload. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow

But there are push state listeners I cant recall them or where it is on mdn, a quick stackoverflow search for "pushstate event listeners" pulled up this:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event){
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

but thats jquery so probably wont work but if you find the push/pop listeners please share.

And there is of course the god solution of nsIWebProgressListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebProgressListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIWebProgressListener#onStatusChange%28%29

but that can get messy as it has a ton of data, but if you understand it, it is the ideal solution.

edit:
oh here is a push/pop listener: window.onpopstate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

edit:
I found this little experiement i did in the past, with different value for 3rd arg of bool and different event listeners, maybe you can add in window.onpopstate in here and do some more testing and share the results, this would be awesome. https://github.com/Noitidart/event-listener-experiment-DOMC-and-load/blob/master/bootstrap.js